# Using variable inplace of table in select statment in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
declare @var sysname
declare @sql varchar(5000)
set @var = 'Table_name'

set @sql = 'select * from ' + @var
exec (@sql)
```

I don't want to use the above script.

It is not working using the below mentioned script.

```
declare @var sysname
set @var = 'Table_name'

select * from @var
```

Is there any way other than apart from using a dynamic query? I want to use something like the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible. If the name of a table is determined dynamically, the only way to use it in a SELECT statement would be via EXEC.